# How to add text-shadow button to tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce, css

I'm using tinymce 3.5.6 and I want to add a button then will work like Bold or Underline buttons, but will add text-shadow to the selected text.

First of all I added "textshadow" to the line

```
theme_advanced_buttons1
```

and added all this lines:

```
'formats' : {
    'textshadow' : {
        'inline' : 'span',
        'styles' : {
            'text-shadow' : '0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
        }
    }
},

'setup' : function (ed) {
    ed.addButton('textshadow', {
        'title' : 'Text shadow',
        'image' : 'js/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/textshadow.png',
        'onclick' : function () {
            ed.formatter.apply('textshadow');
            return false;
        }
    });
},
```

This is works, but not function like Bold or Underline buttons.
When I select text and click on the text-shadow button, it's adding a shadow to the selected text, but it's not remove the shadow on second click.
Also when I selected text with text-shadow it's not selecting (mark as on) the text-shadow button.

What I need to do to make the taxt-shadow button work exactly like Bold or Underline buttons?

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/8wGYC/1/ (the first button is the text-shadow with the flash icon)

**EDIT:**
Other solution, to make extra dropdown menu with 3 options to different shadows. But I want it to work just like the Format dropdown menu (mark on the one is selected, second click will cancel the shadow)
I dont want it to be part from Styles or Format dropdown menus. I want it to be in separate dropdown menu.
I don't know how to do this... any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your `JSfiddle` I was able to find a way around for your problem. I don't know whether it is right but it works very good... :)

***Here is the tiny MCE code with my edits***

```
var toggle=0;
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "textshadow, save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/example.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
                username : "Some User",
                staffid : "991234"
        },
        'formats' : {
            'textshadow' : {
                'inline' : 'span',
                'styles' : {
                    'text-shadow' : '0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
                }
            },
            'noshadow' : {
                'inline' : 'span',
                'styles' : {
                    'text-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                }
            }
        },

        'setup' : function (ed) {
            ed.addButton('textshadow', {
                'title' : 'Text shadow',
                'image' : 'http://www.tinymce.com/js/tinymce_3_x/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/flash.gif',
                'onclick' : function () {
                    if(!toggle){
                    ed.formatter.apply('textshadow');
                        toggle=!0;
                    }
                    else{
                      ed.formatter.apply('noshadow');
                        toggle=0;  
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        },
});
```

I have defined a variable outside named `toggle`. and an extra format named `noshadow` which I set based on toggle value :)

I even tried removing format as specified in this [link](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3aformats) but it didn't work out for me. But I did make it work :)

Comment: This is an example of what you did... http://jsfiddle.net/8wGYC/10/
This is not a good solution because if you mark a text and make it with text-shadow and then want to mark other text to make it with text-shadow it wont work (because "toggle" flag is on anyway)

Comment: Yes.. got that.. In that case one will have to click it twice.. Ya not a good solution. Just played with your fiddle :P

Comment: @Nir I dont know tinyMCE much.. but if you could figure out selection event.. and see which inline-span have been applied.. then toggle can be removed for applying noshadow..